# how to force open my app on both android and iPhone when receive notification?

Tags: android, ios, firebase, react-native, push-notification

I am new in react-native, and what I want is to open the app when receiving notification and show to user an info screen .

it is possible to force open the app when receiving notification? either push notification or firebase notification?

Comment: for `ios` it just not possible.

Comment: In Android onMessageReceived() method  will call when you get new notification so you can open your activity from that.

Comment: It would be better to explain your actual use case rather than what you are trying to do. Here you will only get an answer yes / no to this issue, in this case no, and have nowhere else to go. Where as if you explain the use case (e.g. trying to build a VOIP app that opens on notification delivered), there may be another way to achieve the same outcome, but in a very different way. Always explain what you are trying to achieve and how you are trying to do it, otherwise the answers you get will be limited to the info you give us

Comment: @SimonMcLoughlin Sorry this is my first question, it is not a VOIP app, I edit my question, can I use PushKit?  or it just for VOIP app?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to open an app when user receive a notification. It is not possible because it's user choice to tap on notification to open the app and view the details.